# How to get the text from a random set textview?

Tags: android, textview

I just started with developing an android app. And this app is just a random quotes app. 
Now i am trying to get the text from a randomly quote textview. But it returns false.

```
public class DisplayQuoteActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_quote);

    final String[] listQuotes = {"Quote one","A million or so","Really don't care","Looks like it","Day is done!"};

    Random randGen = new Random();
    int rando = randGen.nextInt(5);

    TextView textQuote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewQuote);
    textQuote.setText(listQuotes[rando]);
}


/** Called when an user wants to share a quote**/
public void shareQuote(View view){
    Log.d("test_app","Share Quote been pushed");
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = this.getString(R.id.viewQuote);// "Here is the share content body";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

}

shareBody seems to be false.

How do i get the text from the textview viewQuote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `textQuote` a global variable and replace

```
 String shareBody = this.getString(R.id.viewQuote);
```

with

```
 String shareBody = textQuote.getText().toString();
```

Comment: tx, made your suggestion to work by using `String shareBody = textQuote.getText().toString();` and making textQuote a global variable

Comment: btw do you have any suggestions which strategy to follow to incorporate 500 different quotes and weekly added quotes? Should i use text file or database? thanks in advance

Comment: A Database will be easier to insert and retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use simply this one

```
textQuote.getText().toString();
```

i.e.

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewQuote)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: thx your suggestion works also. But as a noob which solution would you recommend yours or Apoorv by making textQuote global?

Comment: Depends on how many times you access the `TextView`. If you access it more than once: rather add a global `textQuote`/String field as _Apoorv_ proposed. If you access it only one time, mine above is fine as well. If you are familar with Java and annotations, AndroidAnnotations (http://androidannotations.org/) might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
String shareBody = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewQuote)).getText();
```

Comment: sorry your suggestion gives this message: `missmatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String`

Comment: Yeah, right.. you need to do textView.getText().toString(). I forgot that..sorry. Basically, characterSequence is an interface, that String implements. The parent-to-child binding issue.